# Cannot find name 'canActivate'

Tags: angular, angular-router-guards, canactivate

Guys i'm trying to make a auth guard to guard routes that someone who isnt authenticated cannot access. In my AuthService i imported Can Activate like this:

```
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
```

I also used the implements in the export like this:

```
export class AuthService implements CanActivate {
```

And i created the canActivate mathod like this:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
  if(!this.isAuthenticated()){
    this.logout();
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

But when i try to use it in the const routes in the app-routing.module it throws an error saying that it could not find name 'canActivate' (im removing the imports just to save some space)

```
    canActivate: [AuthService],
    children: [
      {
        path: 'dashboard', 
        loadChildren: () => import() },
      {  
        path: '', 
        loadChildren: () => import() },
      { 
        path: 'modules', 
        loadChildren: () => import() },
      { 
        path: 'settings', 
        loadChildren: () => import() }
    ]
```

The errors i'g getting are "Cannot find name 'canActivate'" and "Cannot find name 'children'". Does someone have any idea of what could be the cause of this?

Comment: have you imported all necessary files in appmodules

Comment: I think so? I'm passing the AuthService as a provider in my app.module

Comment: probably a comma or bracket placed wrong somewhere. It's better if you show all the files, or provide a minimal reproduction example (preferable on stackblitz)

Comment: You're right, it really was a bracket misplaced. Thanks I looked more closely and find out where it was wrong :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys i misplaced some things and that was why it was throwing an error, thanks for the comments :)